# Amazon SP-API Integration

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to integrate Amazon SP-API in my Ecommerce site.

I am trying to Create a feed document. (https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/use-case-guides/feeds-api-use-case-guide/feeds-api-use-case-guide_2021-06-30.md#step-1-create-a-feed-document)

```
// Use Amazon Helper class to create Oauth Access Token
$amazonmwshelper = new AmazonMWSHelper();
$response = $amazonmwshelper->getAmazonAccessToken();
$response = json_decode($response);
$access_token = $response->access_token;

// Amazon SP API request url and variable
$selling_partner_api_live_url = "https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com";
$host = "sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com";

$seller_central_url = "https://sellercentral-europe.amazon.com";
$feed_document_url = "/feeds/2021-06-30/documents";
$market_placeID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$aws_access_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$aws_secret_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$aws_region = "eu-west-1";
$service = 'execute-api';
$algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
$alg = 'sha256';
$uri = $feed_document_url;
$feed_content_type = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
$httpRequestMethod = "POST";

// Create date and datetime acc to Amazon AWS
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
$amazon_date = str_replace('-', '', $current_date);
$amazon_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$amazon_datetime = str_replace(' ', 'T', $amazon_datetime);
$amazon_datetime = str_replace('-', '', $amazon_datetime);
$amazon_datetime = str_replace(':', '', $amazon_datetime);
$amazon_datetime = $amazon_datetime . "Z";

// Data Parameter (Create Payload)
$json_array = [];
$json_array["contentType"] = $feed_content_type;
$param = json_encode($json_array);
$requestPayload = strtolower($param);
$hashedPayload = hash($alg, $requestPayload);

// CREATE CANONICAL REQUEST AND CANONICAL STRING
$canonical_uri = $uri;
$canonical_querystring = '';
$canonical_headers = "host:".$host."\n"."x-amz-access-token:".$access_token."\n"."x-amz-date: ".$amazon_datetime;
$signed_headers = "host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date";
$canonical_request_string = $httpRequestMethod."\n".$canonical_uri."\n".$canonical_querystring."\n".$canonical_headers."\n".$signed_headers."\n".$hashedPayload;

$credential_scope = $amazon_date . "/" . $aws_region . "/" . $service . "/aws4_request";
$string_to_sign  = $algorithm."\n".$amazon_datetime."\n".$credential_scope."\n".hash($alg, $canonical_request_string);

$kSecret = 'AWS4' . $aws_secret_key;
$kDate = hash_hmac( $alg, $amazon_date, $kSecret, true );
$kRegion = hash_hmac( $alg, $aws_region, $kDate, true );
$kService = hash_hmac( $alg, $service, $kRegion, true );
$kSigning = hash_hmac( $alg, 'aws4_request', $kService, true );
$signature = hash_hmac( $alg, $string_to_sign, $kSigning );

$authorization_header = $algorithm . ' ' . 'Credential=' . $aws_access_key . '/' . $credential_scope . ', ' .  'SignedHeaders=' . $signed_headers . ', ' . 'Signature=' . $signature;

$headers = [
            'x-amz-access-token' => $access_token,
            'x-amz-date' => $amazon_datetime,
            'Authorization' => $authorization_header
        ];

// OPERATION => createFeedDocument
$client = new Client();

$feed_response = $client->post($selling_partner_api_live_url . $feed_document_url, [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'body' => $param
]);

if ($feed_response->getStatusCode() == 200 || $feed_response->getStatusCode() == 201 || $feed_response->getStatusCode() == 202 || $feed_response->getStatusCode() == 203 || $feed_response->getStatusCode() == 204) {
    $content = json_decode($feed_response->getBody()->getContents());
    print_r($content);
} else {
    print_r(json_decode($feed_response));
}
```

But i am keep getting the below error.

```
"errors": [
        {
            "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. }]
```

Comment: Did you already "_Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method_" and/or "_Consult the service documentation for details._"?

Comment: @brombeer i created the IAM user and i am using aws accesskey and secret key for signing as mentioned in documentation(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html). i dont know if i am generating the right Payload(hashedPayload )

Comment: Hi @Pankaj, Amazon updated their SP-API documentation recently. They have officialized at https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/ what they previously had at https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs. Probably you can find better insight there.

Comment: @brombeer seems like your missing your host header.

Comment: @MansonXasthur Me? I don't t think so ;)

Comment: @brombeer I see you're missing the host header in the $headers value

Comment: Also you can check this repo for a class named `Signature` you can compare it against your work: https://github.com/mansonxasthur/amazon-sp-api

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're integrating using PHP, here's how to retrieve using the [`jlevers/selling-partner-api`](https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api) library (disclaimer, I'm the developer):

```php
use SellingPartnerApi\Api\FeedsV20210630Api as FeedsApi;
use SellingPartnerApi\Configuration;
use SellingPartnerApi\Endpoint;
use SellingPartnerApi\FeedType;
use SellingPartnerApi\Model\FeedsV20210630 as Feeds;

$config = new Configuration([
    "lwaClientId" => "amzn1.application-oa2-client.....",
    "lwaClientSecret" => "abcd....",
    "lwaRefreshToken" => "Aztr|IwEBI....",
    "awsAccessKeyId" => "AKIA....",
    "awsSecretAccessKey" => "ABCD....",
    // If you're not working in the North American marketplace, change
    // this to another endpoint from lib/Endpoint.php
    "endpoint" => Endpoint::NA,
    // This key/value pair is only necessary if you created your SP API application in Seller Central with a role ARN rather than a user ARN
    "roleArn" => "<Role ARN>",
]);

$feedType = FeedType::POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA;
$feedsApi = new FeedsApi($config);

// Create feed document
$createFeedDocSpec = new Feeds\CreateFeedDocumentSpecification(['content_type' => $feedType['contentType']]);
$feedDocumentInfo = $feedsApi->createFeedDocument($createFeedDocSpec);
$feedDocumentId = $feedDocumentInfo->getFeedDocumentId();

// Upload feed contents to document
$feedContents = file_get_contents('<path/to/your/feed/file.xml>');
$docToUpload = new SellingPartnerApi\Document($feedDocumentInfo, $feedType);
$docToUpload->upload($feedContents);

$createFeedSpec = new Feeds\CreateFeedSpecification();
$createFeedSpec->setMarketplaceIds(['ATVPDKIKX0DER']);
$createFeedSpec->setInputFeedDocumentId($feedDocumentId);
$createFeedSpec->setFeedType($feedType['name']);

$createFeedResult = $feedsApi->createFeed($createFeedSpec);
$feedId = $createFeedResult->getFeedId();
```

If you want to see the feed result processing document, you can download it with the code below. Note that you need to wait for the feed to finish processing for this to work – you can tell if it's done processing if the result of calling `FeedsApi::getFeed()` with the `$feedId` from the previous code block shows that the feed processing status is `DONE`.

```php
$feed = $feedsApi->getFeed($feedId);

$feedResultDocumentId = $feed->resultFeedDocumentId;
$feedResultDocument = $feedsApi->getFeedDocument($feedResultDocumentId);

$docToDownload = new SellingPartnerApi\Document($feedResultDocument, $feedType);
$contents = $docToDownload->download();  // The raw report data
$data = $docToDownload->getData();  // Parsed/formatted report data
```

There's a more complete guide to getting started with the Selling Partner API (including IAM setup) on our website, [here](https://www.highsidelabs.co/blog/spapi-php-library).